# VB.NET Review my regex (My own learnining purpose) Trying not to be greedy

Tags: regex

as last time i will start by saying please don't suggest other Net methods because i am wanting to learn regex. This is purely for my own learning so here goes.

Being greedy may work but it's not always the answer and i guess could cause future issues and bad results. Take this example text, and yes it is an unusual format i am just playing

{regex}Hello World  GET a1b2c3{regex}

The part i am after is "a1b2c32" which would only ever be a letter or number but would always end with a { and start with a white space. My first attempt was a positive look a head.

```
(?<={regex}Hello World  GET )[a-z0-9]+(?={regex})
```

But then i fought about matching any char that is not a curly bracket

```
"Hello World  GET [^{]+"
```

I do realize this would capture the text which i dont want and reference into group1. Basically i am just looking for improvements to my first example if any can be made. It's all about learning and testing for me so it's no real life project.

Thank you all for taking the time to read :)

Comment: You could capture the interesting part with parentheses

Comment: I know you're just learning, but you present several general issues. On the face of it you just want `\s([a-z0-9]+){`, using delimeters `\s`-`{`. However, the regex can look different depending on what you theoretically want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a more general regex:

```
[^{ ]+(?={)
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/wS7uM3)

`[^{ ]+` matches any character except `{` and space and the `+` ensures that there's at least one character so that you don't match the empty string at the very start of the string.

The positive lookahead shouldn't be difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Given the description of the problem, I think this would be sufficient:

```
[a-z0-9]+(?=\{)
```